# SwiftUI : binding value from function

Tags: swiftui

I would like to binding value from a function. But I have the following error :

`Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Binding<Int>'`

Example code :

```
struct MyFirstView: View {

  var body: some View {
    MySecondView(index: getIndex())
  }
  
  func getIndex() -> Int {
    /* Code to get the index.... */
        
    return index
  }
}

struct MySecondView: View {
  
  @Binding var index: Int

  var body: some View {
    Text("Current index : ", index)
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why a `Binding`? If the value is not being modified in `MySecondView` just use a standard property `let index: Int`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just need to generate binding on-the-fly in function (if you really need binding there), like

```
  func getIndex() -> Binding<Int> {
    /* Code to get the index.... */

    return Binding(get: {index}, set: {index = $0})
//    return Binding(get: {index}, set: {_ in }) // alternate 
  }
```